# Static function returning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, static-methods

I have the following piece of code .

```
class base {

private:
    static base *b_h;
public:
    static base* getInstance() {
        if(!b_h) {
            b_h = new base();
        }
        return b_h;
    }
};
    
int main()
{
    base* b;
    b = base::getInstance();

    return 0;
 }
```

When i try to compile, I am facing the below error :

main.cpp:(.text._ZN4base11getInstanceEv[_ZN4base11getInstanceEv]+0x15): undefined reference to `base::b_h' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN4base11getInstanceEv[_ZN4base11getInstanceEv]+0x1c): undefined reference to` base::b_h'

Can someone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the static member outside the class and in exactly one compilation unit (.cpp file).

```
base* base::b_h = nullptr;
```

Alternatively make it a static variable inside the `getInstance()` function:

```
class base {
  public:
    static base* getInstance() {
      static base *b_h = new base();
      return b_h;
    }
};
```

`b_h` will be initialised the first time `getInstance` is called.

---

But in general try to void the singleton pattern if possible.

Comment: Also important to note: this definition should be in a single translation unit (`.cpp` file), generally _not_ in the header.

Comment: @Thomas Yes. Looked like OP has only a main.cpp, but I edited the missing point into the answer.

Comment: @bitmask If I put the static variable inside getInstance , will I get the same copy everytime ?

Comment: @Somesh Yes you will.